# Catch and format FluentValidation's error response

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to catch and re-throw the error produced by a validator in FluentValidation?

I've tried using a custom middleware but it doesn't get hit.

EDIT:
The only way I got this to work is to get dirty and disable all model validation, by setting `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;` and using an `Action Filter`, but I really don't like this approach since I don't want to lose the model's validation everywhere in the app.

Comment: How you are invoking your fluent validators?  If you are calling it manually you must use ValidateAndThrow or ValidateAndThrowAsync

Comment: Do you mean you want to manually validate an object in a MVC project? If that is the case, the validation results can be copied to MVC’s modelstate dictionary via the AddToModelState method, refer [the Manual validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#manual-validation).

Comment: @ZhiLv Exactly the opposite. I want to let it do it's job, but i want to catch the errors thrown so i can format them by a standard.

Comment: @Alexrgs. No, i do not invoke them manually. I registered FluentValidation by calling AddFluentValidation() on IMVCBuilder

Comment: @BogdanB  Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922693/fluentvalidation-use-custom-iactionfilter